# Data Aggregations over time, when time is variable

Tags: c#, aggregation, modulo

I am in the process of developing an application which calculates the shared acquired in a product over a specified time period (Term).

After the calculations have been performed, it is necessary for me to aggregate the data into groups based on a predefined review period (for example if the time required to gain 100% ownership of the product is 25 years, and the review period value is 5 years, I would have 5 sets of data aggregations for the agreement).

I perform the aggregations as shown by looping through my calculation result set:

```
if (Year% ReviewPeriod == 0)
            {
                // Perform Aggregations
            }
```

This works fine in most scenarios.
However I do have a number of scenarios where the product  reaches 100% ownership before the end of term.

What I need to be able to do is aggregate the calculations performed based on the ReviewPeriod variable, but if the final number of values in the calculations is not equal to the review period, aggregate the items based on the number of items remaining.

For example, given a 22 year term, data would be aggregated based on the Review Period variable, however if there is a remainder, then the remainder should be aggregated based on the value of the remainder.

Worked Example

Year 0 - 5 = 5 Aggregations

Year  6 - 10 = 5 Aggregations

Year  11 - 15 = 5 Aggregations

Year  16 - 20 = 5 Aggregations

Year 21 - 22 = 2 Aggregations

Could anyone help me with the logic to aggregate the data as I have described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be something like:

```
for ( int year = 0; year <= max_year; year++ ) {
    if ( year % reviewPeriod == 0 ) {
        // start a new aggregation
    }
    // add year to current aggregation
}
```

You could keep a list of aggregations and add a new one at the start of each period.

Here is a working example that just groups years in lists:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Aggregations
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int maxYear = 22;
            int period = 5;
            int year = 1985;

            List<List<int>> aggregations = new List<List<int>>();
            int i = -1;
            for (int y = 0; y <= maxYear; y++)
            {
                if (y % period == 0)
                {
                    aggregations.Add(new List<int>());
                    i++;
                }
                aggregations.ElementAt(i).Add(year);
                year++;
            }
            foreach ( List<int> l in aggregations )
            {
                foreach (int yy in l)
                {
                    Console.Write(yy + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. He seems to be performing the aggregation _inside the if statement_, while I suggest that he only _start_ a new aggregation in the if, but perform it in the body of the loop. In this way remaining years would be correctly added to the last aggregation.

Comment: ah, ok, sorry, you meant "start". I've misread your comment. You're right - if he does it incrementally, then he probably forgot to reset the counters somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, your code helped me form the basis of my solution. Many thanks to everone who answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think my suggestion is not worth 300rep bounty, and either I misunderstood your problem, or you've overshot the bounty..

Do your existing code that calculates the final aggregations works well? If so, then to determine the ranges yo umay just use modulo (%) and simple math:

```
int minYear = ...the first year // inclusive, i.e. 1970
int maxYear = ...the last year // inclusive, i.e. 2012

int span = maxYear - minYear + 1; // 1970..2012->43, 2001..2006->6

int fullFives = span / 5; // 1970..2012->8, 2001..2006->1
int remainder = span % 5; // 2001..2006->3, 2001..2006->1

for(int i=0; i<fullFives; ++i)
{
    int yearFrom = minYear + 5*i
    int yearTo = minYear + 5*(i+1) - 1

    // 1970..2012 -> 1970-1974, 1975-1979,1980-1984,1985-1989,1990-1994,1995-1999,2000-2004,2005-2009
    // 2001..2006 -> 2001-2005

    aggregate(yearFrom, yearTo);
}

if(remainder > 0)
{
    int yearFrom = minYear + 5*fullFives
    int yearTo = minYear + maxYear

    // 1970..2012 -> 2010-2012
    // 2001..2006 -> 2006-2006

    aggregate(yearFrom, yearTo);
}
```

This is written "out of thin air", I've not checked/compiled it - it is just to sketch the idea.

Note: you've said that everything works but sometimes "a number of scenarios where the product reaches 100% ownership before the end of term." - that would suggest that you rather have an error in the calculations, not in the looping. If the error were in the loop or year boundary detection, then probably almost all would be off. It's hard to say without more of the calculating code is revealed.

Answer (score 1):

You've not really given enough of your code to go on. Hopefully you should be able to use this however your loop is currently set up. It "leaks" the mod value to the outside of the loop; after the loop is over, you can check the final mod value to see how many aggregations are left.

```
int modValue = 0;
for //foreach/while/... - your loop here
{
    ...
    modValue = Year % ReviewPeriod;
    if (modValue == 0)
    {
        // Perform Aggregations
    }  
    ...
} // end of your loop

if (modValue != 0)
{
    // Perform final aggregation. There are modValue items to aggregate.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code sample will fire on years 0, 5, 10 etc rather than for every year.

If you just need the number of years to aggregate when that code fires, and the term can be set in advance when a product reaches 100% ownership early, I think this would work:

```
        int term = 22;
        int reviewperiod = 5;

        for (int year = 0; year < term; year++)
        {
            if (year % reviewperiod == 0)
            {
                var endyear = Math.Min(year + reviewperiod, term);
                Console.WriteLine("Aggregate years {0} to {1}, {2} Aggregations ", year, endyear, endyear - year);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you think of something like

```
private int reviewPeriod = 5;

public void Aggregate(int term)
{
    Enumerable.Range(0, term)
        .ToList()
        .Foreach(this.AggregateYear);
}
```

when `this.AggregateYear` is defined as follows

```
public void AggregateYear(int year)
{
    var currentRemainder = year % this.reviewPeriod;
    var aggregatePeriod = (currentRemainder == 0)
        ? this.reviewPeriod
        : currentRemainder;
    this.PerformAggregation(aggregatePeriod);
}
```

and `this.PerformAggregation` is defined as follows

```
private void PerformAggregation(int aggregatePeriod)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this data is in memory (since you have not specified otherwise), then you can just use the GroupBy function from Linq:

```
struct YearValue 
{
    public int Year, Value; 
}

static void Main()
{
    // Create some data, hopefully representative of what you are dealing with...
    Random r = new Random();
    YearValue[] dataValues = new YearValue[22];
    for (int i = 0; i < dataValues.Length; i++)
        dataValues[i] = new YearValue {Year = i, Value = r.Next(200)};

    // Average of values across 'ReviewPeriod' of five:
    foreach (var item in dataValues.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(i => i.Year / 5))
    {
        YearValue[] items = item.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("Group {0} had {1} item(s) averaging {2}",
                          item.Key,
                          items.Length,
                          items.Average(i => i.Value)
            );
    }
}
```

This program then outputs the following text:

```
Group 0 had 5 item(s) averaging 143.6
Group 1 had 5 item(s) averaging 120.4
Group 2 had 5 item(s) averaging 83
Group 3 had 5 item(s) averaging 145.2
Group 4 had 2 item(s) averaging 98.5
```